# How to make a combined score from multiple test

Tags: statsmodels

I have a bunch of tests done on individuals who have a genetic susceptibility to ADHD and others who don’t have that susceptibility. I have to come up with a point system to score these individuals to determine if they do have ADHD. I have performed analyses such as Wilcoxin tests and proportional odds tests (on binary dependent variables) to determine whether the performance on certain measures/tests is higher in those not susceptible to ADHD. I now have an idea of what tests and measures are important to see if someone has ADHD but I need to come up with a scoring system to rate overall performance on these tests. The problem is some of the dependent measures are all different such as some were pass/fail (binary), some were percentages, some were counts, some were also molecular measures such as concentration of certain bio markers. How would you go about scoring the overall performance on these tests? Is there any statistical methods I can use to do this or at least verify the system once I make one?

Thanks!

Comment: "[S]ome of the dependent measures are all different" or some of the independent measures are all different?  It sounds to me like you are wanting to take measurements/scores on various tests and use these to predict will get ADHD (or is at high risk perhaps) vs. will not get ADHD, right?  In this case those measurements will be independent variables, right?  Or are you wanting to do something with multivariate analyses, predicting multiple scores (as a vector) at a time?

Comment: Another question I would have is if all the individuals in your study are independent?  Do any of the subjects come from the same family perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The independent variable in this study is those that have the genetic predisposition to ADHD (based on family history) vs dont have the genetic predisposition. The dependent variables are the performance on the various tests such as concentration tests, then there are subjective ratings of various symptoms, measures of biomarkers, ct scan results etc... All the subjects are independent. Also, my goal is to determine those that already have ADHD (based on the scoring system) and then hopefully this can be used in the future as a way of diagnosing ADHD.